# ¿Por qué no se visualiza los registros en proyecto laravel dentro de un componente vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estimados ¡Buenas noches!; Para "Listar las categorías en la vista"; explicó que vamos a crear un componente vue (el el directorio del proyecto de laravel) /resources/js/components/Categoria.vue; para lo cual se copia el código que estaba como ejemplo en el componente de la misma carpeta archivo /resources/js/components/Example-components.vue (que posteriormente va hacer eliminado el archivo); en el archivo de "Categoria.vue"; en la parte de abajo del archivo dentro de la etiqueta , se va a crear una función que se llama data() y a la vez va a tener una función que se llama return(), que va tener las variables de los campos nombre, descripción y se declara una variable que se llama ArrayCategoria:[], luego de ello definimos los metodos (que para ello creamos un metodo que se llama listarCategoria()), que incluimos el código de la herramiento axios; que en la ruta definido por el archivo web.php (que esta en la carpeta /routes), tiene este contenido: Archivo (/routes/web.php)

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('contenido/contenido');
});

Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');

?>
```

Lo que quiere decir que con la ruta /categoria (para la primera), hace la llamada al Controlador CategoriaController y la función index que esta en la carpeta /App/Http/Controllers/CategoriaController.php); que en la función index tiene lo siguiente:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Categoria;

class CategoriaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $categorias= Categoria::all();
        return $categorias;
       
    }

    

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= new Categoria();
        $categoria->nombre= $request->nombre;
        $categoria->descripcion= $request->descripcion;
        $categoria->condicion= '1';
        $categoria->save();
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= Categoria::findOrFail($request->id);
        $categoria->nombre= $request->nombre;
        $categoria->descripcion= $request->descripcion;
        $categoria->condicion= '1';
        $categoria->save();
    }

    public function desactivar(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= Categoria::findOrFail($request->id);
        $categoria->condicion= '0';
        $categoria->save();
    }

    public function activar(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= Categoria::findOrFail($request->id);
        $categoria->condicion= '1';
        $categoria->save();
    }

    
}
```

Ahora bien el contenido del la parte de abajo que esta entre las etiquetas  del archivo (/resources/js/components/Categoria.vue); esta el siguiente código:

```js
<script>
   
    export default {
        data(){

            return {

                nombre:'',
                descripcion:'',
                arrayCategoria:[]
            }

        },

        methods:{

           listarCategoria(){

               let me=this;

               axios.get('/categoria').then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.arrayCategoria=response.data;
                    
                    
                   
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });
           }
        
        },
        
        mounted() {
            //console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.listarCategoria();
        }
    }
</script>
```

y Que luego explico que en la parte de arriba del archivo "Categoria.vue" luego de declarar la etiqueta , juego desde donde se forma la tabla para la información, vamos a usar unas directivas v-if, v-else y v-text; de esta manera:

```html
 <tr v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id">
                                    
                                    <td v-text="categoria.nombre"></td>
                                    <td v-text="categoria.descripcion"></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" v-if="categoria.condicion">
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Activo
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-else>
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Desactivado
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">

                                          <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i> Editar
                                        </button> &nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td>

                                        
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i> Desactivar
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
```

Que adjunto el código completo del archivo (/resources/js/components/Categoria.vue) de todo lo indicado:

```html
<template>
   <main class="main">
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="/">BACKEND - SISTEMA DE COMPRAS - VENTAS</a></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">

                       <h2>Listado de Categorías</h2><br/>
                      
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#abrirmodal">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Agregar Categoría
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control col-md-3">
                                      <option value="nombre">Categoría</option>
                                      <option value="descripcion">Descripción</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar texto">
                                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-primary">
                                   
                                    <th>Categoría</th>
                                    <th>Descripción</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                    <th>Editar</th>
                                    <th>Cambiar Estado</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               
                                <tr v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id">
                                    
                                    <td v-text="categoria.nombre"></td>
                                    <td v-text="categoria.descripcion"></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" v-if="categoria.condicion">
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Activo
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-else>
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Desactivado
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">

                                          <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i> Editar
                                        </button> &nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td>

                                        
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i> Desactivar
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                               
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Anterior</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item active">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">4</a>
                                </li>
                               
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Siguiente</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fin ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
            </div>
            <!--Inicio del modal agregar/actualizar-->
            <div class="modal fade" id="abrirmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar categoría</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            
                            <div class="form-group row div-error">
                                
                                <div class="text-center text-error">
                                    
                                    <div></div>

                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                             

                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Categoría</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de categoría">
                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="email-input">Descripción</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese descripcion">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i> Cerrar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Guardar</button>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!--Fin del modal-->
           
        
        </main>
</template>

<script>
   
    export default {
        data(){

            return {

                nombre:'',
                descripcion:'',
                arrayCategoria:[]
            }

        },

        methods:{

           listarCategoria(){

               let me=this;

               axios.get('/categoria').then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.arrayCategoria=response.data;
                    
                    
                   
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });
           }
        
        },
        
        mounted() {
            //console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.listarCategoria();
        }
    }
</script>
```

De todo lo explicado realice la compilación del proyecto npm run watch (desde la ventana terminal del Visual Studio Code); y que luego desde la misma ventana de terminal para ejecutar el proyecto php artisan serve (que al correr en el navegador no muestra la información de la tabla); no lo se ¿cuál es el problema?; espero de sus comentarios estimado instructor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimados, ¡Buenas noches!, de la pantalla capturada que sale con el error, en mi proyecto laravel, en el archivo "web.php" del proyecto que esta en la ruta /routes/web.php esta la ruta adjunto código del archivo "web.php"

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('contenido/contenido');
});

Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');

?>
```

De lo que respecta al controlador "CategoriaController.php" que esta en la ruta del proyecto: /app/Http/Controllers/CategoriaController.php ( que en la parte de arriba esta el codigo del controlador CategoriaController.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimados compile archivo desde la terminal del Visual Studio Code de esta manera npm run watch y luego de varias veces lo volví a compilar con npm run dev
Para correr el proyecto de Lavarel puse php artisan serve. Su ayuda.

Comment: Te esta dando not found el controller...

Comment: A la derecha en la consola se ve un `404`, si hacés click en la URL `/categoria`, cuál es la URL completa que te carga? Me da la sensación de que está cargando `localhost/categoria`, lo cual obviamente es incorrecto.

Comment: Estimados @azeós , ¡Buenas noches!; les saluda el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo desde Ecuador (Guayaquil) con respecto a esto lo que indicas la ruta para el controlador es la siguiente:

Comment: @JoseFernandoFrugoneJaramill no se ve la ruta.

Comment: Estimado @azeós ¡Buenas noches!, te saluda el Lcdo José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo en la parte de arriba de la pregunta esta el código de la ruta del proyecto Archivo "web.php", el controlador "CategoriaController.php", y el componente vue (Categoria.vue) para que análisis el código porque no muestra la información, el proyecto se compilo de esta manera npm run watch, se hizo las pruebas se corrio con php artisan serve; y se volvió a compilar con el comando npm run watch, tu ayuda.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi , ¡Buenas noches!, te saluda el Lcdo José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo en el código que esta arriba del archivo "web.php" (que esta en la carpeta /routes/web.php" es como que no encontrara el archivo "CategoriaController.php" (que es el controlador); que en la parte de arriba esta el código del controlador "CategoriaController.php" ¿Cuál será el problema?

Comment: Jose por favor, te pido que ordenes la pregunta, ya que como esta no se entiende absolutamente nada. Se agradecen los saludos y formalismos, pero por ejemple en este sitio tu nombre figura en una ficha bajo la pregunta. Este sitio trata de mantener las preguntas y respuestas con la menor cantidad de "ruido" posible. Se te pregunto a que url estaba llamando el componente vue, no cual era la ruta que vos declaraste, ya que probablemente el error 404 (que quiere decir que no encuentra la ruta) se deba a eso. Verifica a que ruta quiere acceder la llamada web desde vue

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi ¡Buenas noches! esta clara la pregunta si lo lees deteninamente paso a paso con los códigos de ejemplos que están en la pregunta se entiendo, y lo que te quiero decir que a pesar de definir la ruta no entra al Controlador CategoriaController.php para obtener la información; te pido de ¡por favor!, leas muy detenidamente la pregunta con los códigos que incluyo.

Comment: Jose, en la última imagen de tu pregunta, a la derecha se ve un 404 con fondo rojo que dice `/categoria:1`. Lo que te pido, es que clickees en dicho link y nos digas a que URL te redirecciona.

Comment: Jose, todo lo que pones, no define tu error. Tu error es que el componente VUE no esta llamando a la ruta que vos pensas que esta llamando. @azeós y yo te estamos diciendo que nos digas a que ruta esta llamando el componente. No donde definiste el controlador, si no a que ruta esta llamando el componente. Y siento decirte que por mas que trataste de ser exhaustivo, en este caso tu pregunta quedo muy confusa en relacion a tu problema. Mira por favor [ask]. Aunque esta bien que nos llenes de informacion, en este caso la mayoria es totalmente irrelevante y hace ruido.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi mi componente vue que esta en la ruta /resources/js/components/Categoria.vue con axio en la parte de abqjo del conponente hace referencia a la propiedad categoria que se hace referencia al archivo /routes/web.php de mi proyecto laravel que este mismo archivo de llamar al controlador que esta /app/HTTp/controllers/CategoriaControllers.php de mi proyecto arriba esta el codigo en mi componente vue /resources/js/components/categoria.vue uso axios ¿has escuchado de axios?; ya que no llama al archivo que antes te dije web.php. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi no lo se porque desde mi componente vue /resources/js/components/Categoria.vue (de mi proyecto laravel) no llama al archivo /routes/web.php que cre referencia al controlador CategoriaControllers.php ruta es /app/HTTp/controllers/CategoriaController.php asi te lo explico de esta manera. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Jose creo que no entendes como funciona axios y una llamada desde un componente VUE. No importa lo que pongas en todos los otros lados. El componente esta en una ruta, y la llamada la hace basada en esa ruta. Por lo cual, varias veces ya te preguntamos y te dijimos que te fijaras, al apretar F12, en la pestaña red, cual es la ruta que utilizo para la llamada, porque esa es la ruta que esta mal. Si vos en axios solo escribis Categoria, va a llamar a la ruta donde se esta ejecutan + categoria, que no es la ruta de tu controlador laravel.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi axios que esta en mi component vue /resources/js/components/Categoria.vue hace referencia a la instancia del controladorCategoria que lo define en /routes/web.php de mi proyectolaravel y a su vez desde el archivo antes indicado web.php debe de hacer referencia al controlado /app/HTTp/controllers/CategoriaController.php pero de mi componente vue no llama al controlador desde el archivo /routes/web.php de mi proyectolaravel. Una consulta en mi componente vue hay que incluir alguna sentencia para que llame al archivo /routes/web.php que a la vez hace referencia al controlador.

Comment: Estas totalmente confundido... vue no tiene nada que ver con php, no sabe que hay un php abajo ni sabe que hay laravel ni nada. Vue interactua por si mismo. Vue tiene sus propios archivos de rutas, y por eso te digo, y te pido encarecidamente, que hagas lo que te pedimos, y nos digas a donde esta llamando el componente vue. Si tu pagina bue se lanza como http://localhost/#, cuando hagas la llamada axios a categoria, va a buscar esta ruta: http://localhost/categoria, y no las rutas que estas marcando. Por eso te preguntamos a donde hace la llamada.

Comment: @gbianchi estimado ¿como hago para que desde axios de mi componente vue /resources/js/categoria.vue ya que en script del vue usa axios para que llame o haga referencia a la propiedad categoria que se define en mi archivo /routes/web.php que este archivo debe de llamar al controlador que se llama CategoriaCintroller.php que esta en la ruta /app/HTTp/controllers tengo este problema apoyame

Comment: y vos respondeme a mi. Cual es la ruta a la que llama axios? no cual queres que llame, si no a cual esta llamando actualmente? para eso, como ya te dijimos 3 veces, en la pestaña red de la consola del desarrollador de tu navegador, fijate en la llamada a que ruta llama.

Answer (score 1):

Vue es un framework que nada tiene que ver con laravel o PHP. Es importante entender que todo lo que se haga de un lado, como definir rutas y otras cosas, no tiene nada que ver con lo que pasa del otro lado.

Al hacer tu llamada con axios sin especificar una ruta, de la forma

```
axios.get('/categoria')
```

Lo que hace el navegador, es apendar esa ruta a la ruta actual de tu pagina web.

Por lo tanto, si tu pagina se esta ejecutando aca:

```
http://localhost:8080/#/
```

Entonces axios va a tratar de llamar a

```
http://localhost:8080/#/categoria
```

Lo que vos tenes que hacer, es definirle a axios la ruta donde levantaste tu controlador php.
Cuando hiciste: `php artisan serve`, tu servidor de laravel se levanto en una ruta y un puerto, los cuales no se cuales son. En vue, al usar axios (o cual otro componente para hacer llamadas a controladores), vos le tenes que especificar exactamente cual es la ruta que necesitas.

Por ejemplo, si tu controlador se levanto en el puerto 4560, entonces tu llamada deberia ser

```
axios.get(' http://localhost:4560/categoria')
```

Tene en cuenta que dentro de la pantalla de red, en el navegador, dice a que ruta se hizo cada llamada que hizo tu pagina (incluida las llamadas que hace axios).

Answer (score 0):

Sobre esta pregunta ya esta solucionado un usuario en esta página WEB me indicó que pusiera de esta manera

axios.get('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria');

en el caso de mi proyecto que es proyectolaravel y pude visualizar los registros y quedo solucionado.

Comment: Fue la respuesta que te dio el otro usuario la correcta?